# read multiple data file into multiple arrays python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am new to Python, and I have a problem in dealing with multiple data files.
I want to read multiple data files into multiple arrays, for example, I want to read data in 1c.txt to array c1, data in 2c.txt into c2, etc. And I tried the following code:

```
import numpy as np
for i in range(1,15):
     globals()['c%s' % i] = np.loadtxt(['%sc.txt' % i], usecols=(0,1,2))
```

But it prompted with `IndexError: list index out of range`, and I changed `usecols=(0,1,2)` to `usecols=(0)` it still didn't work, so I think something else must be wrong.

Also I found I could not use the code as:
    `['c%s' % i]`
to get the variable names as c1,c2, etc. And I have to add a `globals()` before the `['c%s' % i]`, but I don't know why.

Waiting online. Many thanks!

Comment: Hi dawg, thank you for your reply. But how to make it?

Comment: If you start thinking of these files as spreadsheets then you might also think about pandas dataframes rather than dicts or numpy arrays.  especially if it's not just numerical data.

Comment: I found the problem, I should use
    np.loadtxt('%sc.txt' % i, usecols=(0,1,2))
instead of:
    np.loadtxt(['%sc.txt' % i], usecols=(0,1,2))
in my code.
Thanks for Ajean and you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can answer at least some of those questions.

> I found I could not use the code as: ['c%s' % i] = np.loadtxt(['%sc.txt' % i]

That is because `['c%i' % i]` will give you a list of strings, not variables. By doing `globals()[string]` you are accessing (assigning) to a dictionary (the globals() dictionary).  I **highly** recommend **NOT** using globals()!

Do something like:

```
mydict = {}
for i in range(1,15):
    mydict['c%i' % i] = np.loadtxt('c%i.txt' % i, usecols=(0,1,2))
```

I also notice that you are using `%s` where you should be using `%i` in your formatting, %s is for strings but your variable `i` is an integer.

Comment: Probably other can expound on it better than I can, but it has to do with the namespaces and how variables are scoped.  It's a general programming practice that global variables are best avoided when possible.  In addition, trying to work directly with the enormous dict that is globals() will just make you work ten times harder than you have to...

Comment: And.... I just saw the excellent comments @dawg made on his just-as-useful answer. Exactly!

Answer (score 2):

You should use a Python [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) to hold a mapping to arrays:

```
import numpy as np

dict_of_arrays={}

for i in range(1,15):
    dict_of_arrays['c%i' % i]=np.array([1,2,3])

print dict_of_arrays
```

Prints:

```
{'c11': array([1, 2, 3]), 'c13': array([1, 2, 3]), 'c9': array([1, 2, 3]), 'c8': array([1, 2, 3]), 'c14': array([1, 2, 3]), 'c12': array([1, 2, 3]), 'c3': array([1, 2, 3]), 'c2': array([1, 2, 3]), 'c1': array([1, 2, 3]), 'c10': array([1, 2, 3]), 'c7': array([1, 2, 3]), 'c6': array([1, 2, 3]), 'c5': array([1, 2, 3]), 'c4': array([1, 2, 3])}
```

Then access an individual array thus: `dict_of_arrays['c11']` to access the data from file c11 as an example.

Comment: That does not change the basic concept that you use a dict to manage multiple data items -- don't try and make variable names by using `globals()`

Comment: would you tell me why?

Comment: A) It is slower than using a local dict; B) It is confusing to others that read your code; C) It is sloppy; D) [It will bite you](http://www.diveintopython.net/html_processing/locals_and_globals.html)

Comment: Thank you! I wish I could mark two best answers! : )